# Azure devops pipelines - pass parameters to template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have azure devops pipeline that runs scheduled tests every night. My main pipeline file looks like this:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml

trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Scheduled test run
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: vm1
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: vm2
    type: boolean
    default: true

stages:
- stage: deploy_and_run_bdd_tests
  jobs:
    - template: pipelines/behave_test.yml
```

From that main pipeline file a template is called (pipelines/behave_test.yml). And my pipelines/behave_test.yml looks like this:

```
# pipelines/behave_test.yml

parameters:
  - name: vm1
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: vm2
    type: boolean
    default: true

jobs:
- ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
  - job: do something
    condition: eq('${{ parameter.Value }}', 'true')
    # do something ...
```

How can I define parameters only in main pipeline file and pass them all to template? If I remove parameters part from behave_test.yml, then my "each" logic breaks in that template. Can I somehow pass parameters to template to avoid duplication and without refactoring template file?